# Solving matrix differential equation, enforcing orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a matrix differential equation of the form

$\partial_t V = T(t) V$

Where T is an antisymmetric matrix (but that has a time dependence so we can not solve this analytically). It can be easily shown that $V$ is orthogonal (if the initial value is orthogonal). I want to solve this numerically, enforcing that $V$ is orthogonal. Using something simple like

$V(t+\Delta t) = V+\Delta t T(t)V$

would not preserve the orthogonality of $V$.

One way of doing it would be to use the numerical scheme

$V(t+\Delta t) = e^{\Delta t T(t)}V$

This preserves orthogonality, however, it requires evaluating a matrix exponential which could be computationally costly (I need to solve this for a real time simulation).

Are there other numerical schemes here that would preserve orthogonality of $V$ but which does not require us to evaluate a matrix exponential? If it helps, the matrices are 4x4.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Padé approximations of the exponential,
$$
X_{+1}=\left(1+\tfrac{Δt}2T\right)\left(1-\tfrac{Δt}2T\right)^{-1}X
$$
or two orders higher
$$
X_{+1}=\left(1+\tfrac{Δt}2T+\tfrac{Δt^2}{12}T^2\right)\left(1-\tfrac{Δt}2T+\tfrac{Δt^2}{12}T^2\right)^{-1}X
$$
The first variant amounts to the implicit RK2 method (midpoint or trapezoidal), I'm not aware of a named 4th order method that results in the second formula.